# CompileLayerT::addModule crashed for no reason

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I'm trying to create a llvm JIT in my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"
#include "KaleidoscopeJIT.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"

int main() {
  llvm::InitializeNativeTarget();
  llvm::InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();
  llvm::InitializeNativeTargetAsmParser();



  llvm::LLVMContext context;
  llvm::orc::KaleidoscopeJIT jit;
  auto module = std::make_unique<llvm::Module>("top", context);
  llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(context);
  module->setDataLayout(jit.getTargetMachine().createDataLayout());



  llvm::FunctionType *funcType = llvm::FunctionType::get(builder.getVoidTy(), false);
  llvm::Function *mainFunc =
      llvm::Function::Create(funcType, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, "main", module.get());
  llvm::BasicBlock *entry = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(context, "", mainFunc);
  builder.SetInsertPoint(entry);
  module->print(llvm::errs(), nullptr);
  auto H = jit.addModule(std::move(module));
  ...
  ...

}
```

when comes to the `addModule`, the program crashed(interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV), I debugged the stack:

```
llvm::Instruction::getNumSuccessors() const 0x0000565102dbd7e0
llvm::BranchProbabilityInfo::updatePostDominatedByUnreachable(llvm::BasicBlock const*) 0x000056510361d797
llvm::BranchProbabilityInfo::calculate(llvm::Function const&, llvm::LoopInfo const&, llvm::TargetLibraryInfo const*) 0x00005651036220ef
llvm::BranchProbabilityInfoWrapperPass::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) 0x00005651036225bd
llvm::FPPassManager::runOnFunction(llvm::Function&) 0x0000565102ddc640
llvm::FPPassManager::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) 0x0000565102ddc8b3
llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) 0x0000565102ddcc7e
llvm::orc::SimpleCompiler::operator() CompileUtils.h:68
llvm::orc::LegacyIRCompileLayer<llvm::orc::LegacyRTDyldObjectLinkingLayer, llvm::orc::SimpleCompiler>::addModule IRCompileLayer.h:84
llvm::orc::KaleidoscopeJIT::addModule KaleidoscopeJIT.h:66
main main.cpp:34
__libc_start_main 0x00007f8d8ee38b97
_start 0x0000565102cdc1ca
```

The KaleidoscopeJIT.h:

```
//===- KaleidoscopeJIT.h - A simple JIT for Kaleidoscope --------*- C++ -*-===//
//
// Part of the LLVM Project, under the Apache License v2.0 with LLVM Exceptions.
// See https://llvm.org/LICENSE.txt for license information.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0 WITH LLVM-exception
//
//===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//
//
// Contains a simple JIT definition for use in the kaleidoscope tutorials.
//
//===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//

#ifndef LLVM_EXECUTIONENGINE_ORC_KALEIDOSCOPEJIT_H
#define LLVM_EXECUTIONENGINE_ORC_KALEIDOSCOPEJIT_H

#include "llvm/ADT/STLExtras.h"
#include "llvm/ADT/iterator_range.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/ExecutionEngine.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/JITSymbol.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/CompileUtils.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/IRCompileLayer.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/LambdaResolver.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/RTDyldObjectLinkingLayer.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/RTDyldMemoryManager.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/SectionMemoryManager.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DataLayout.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Mangler.h"
#include "llvm/Support/DynamicLibrary.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"
#include "llvm/Target/TargetMachine.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace llvm {
namespace orc {

class KaleidoscopeJIT {
public:
  using ObjLayerT = LegacyRTDyldObjectLinkingLayer;
  using CompileLayerT = LegacyIRCompileLayer<ObjLayerT, SimpleCompiler>;

  KaleidoscopeJIT()
      : Resolver(createLegacyLookupResolver(
            ES,
            [this](const std::string &Name) {
              return ObjectLayer.findSymbol(Name, true);
            },
            [](Error Err) { cantFail(std::move(Err), "lookupFlags failed"); })),
        TM(EngineBuilder().selectTarget()), DL(TM->createDataLayout()),
        ObjectLayer(ES,
                    [this](VModuleKey) {
                      return ObjLayerT::Resources{
                          std::make_shared<SectionMemoryManager>(), Resolver};
                    }),
        CompileLayer(ObjectLayer, SimpleCompiler(*TM)) {
    llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::LoadLibraryPermanently(nullptr);
  }

  TargetMachine &getTargetMachine() { return *TM; }

  VModuleKey addModule(std::unique_ptr<Module> M) {
    auto K = ES.allocateVModule();
    cantFail(CompileLayer.addModule(K, std::move(M)));
    ModuleKeys.push_back(K);
    return K;
  }

  void removeModule(VModuleKey K) {
    ModuleKeys.erase(find(ModuleKeys, K));
    cantFail(CompileLayer.removeModule(K));
  }

  JITSymbol findSymbol(const std::string Name) {
    return findMangledSymbol(mangle(Name));
  }

private:
  std::string mangle(const std::string &Name) {
    std::string MangledName;
    {
      raw_string_ostream MangledNameStream(MangledName);
      Mangler::getNameWithPrefix(MangledNameStream, Name, DL);
    }
    return MangledName;
  }

  JITSymbol findMangledSymbol(const std::string &Name) {
#ifdef _WIN32
    // The symbol lookup of ObjectLinkingLayer uses the SymbolRef::SF_Exported
    // flag to decide whether a symbol will be visible or not, when we call
    // IRCompileLayer::findSymbolIn with ExportedSymbolsOnly set to true.
    //
    // But for Windows COFF objects, this flag is currently never set.
    // For a potential solution see: https://reviews.llvm.org/rL258665
    // For now, we allow non-exported symbols on Windows as a workaround.
    const bool ExportedSymbolsOnly = false;
#else
    const bool ExportedSymbolsOnly = true;
#endif

    // Search modules in reverse order: from last added to first added.
    // This is the opposite of the usual search order for dlsym, but makes more
    // sense in a REPL where we want to bind to the newest available definition.
    for (auto H : make_range(ModuleKeys.rbegin(), ModuleKeys.rend()))
      if (auto Sym = CompileLayer.findSymbolIn(H, Name, ExportedSymbolsOnly))
        return Sym;

    // If we can't find the symbol in the JIT, try looking in the host process.
    if (auto SymAddr = RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddressInProcess(Name))
      return JITSymbol(SymAddr, JITSymbolFlags::Exported);

#ifdef _WIN32
    // For Windows retry without "_" at beginning, as RTDyldMemoryManager uses
    // GetProcAddress and standard libraries like msvcrt.dll use names
    // with and without "_" (for example "_itoa" but "sin").
    if (Name.length() > 2 && Name[0] == '_')
      if (auto SymAddr =
              RTDyldMemoryManager::getSymbolAddressInProcess(Name.substr(1)))
        return JITSymbol(SymAddr, JITSymbolFlags::Exported);
#endif

    return nullptr;
  }

  ExecutionSession ES;
  std::shared_ptr<SymbolResolver> Resolver;
  std::unique_ptr<TargetMachine> TM;
  const DataLayout DL;
  ObjLayerT ObjectLayer;
  CompileLayerT CompileLayer;
  std::vector<VModuleKey> ModuleKeys;
};

} // end namespace orc
} // end namespace llvm

#endif // LLVM_EXECUTIONENGINE_ORC_KALEIDOSCOPEJIT_H
```

But if I run codes in https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl04.html, it works well, so I guess the environment is right.

Any idea why it crashed?

Comment: Seems like your module is incorrect: you have a function with an empty basic block, it should have at least one (terminator) instruction.

Answer (score 0):

AlexDenisov's comment is right: BasicBlocks should end with terminator instructions. Try adding

```
builder.CreateRetVoid();
```

to your code between the call to `builder.setInsertPoint` and `module->print`.